# How to read excel application version from xls (Excel97) files?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

When using NPOI `WorkbookFactory` with a "modern" Excel file (*.xlsx) it produces an XSSFWorkbook, which contains the Excel-version:

```
xssfWorkbook.GetProperties().ExtendedProperties.AppVersion
```

This returns the Excel version number, e.g. "`16.0300`".

Is there a way to get this information for a HSSFWorkbook?

BTW: The name of the application is available in both classes:

```
hssfWorkbook.SummaryInformation.ApplicationName
xssfWorkbook.GetProperties().ExtendedProperties.Application
```

For MS Excel, this is "`Microsoft Excel`" in both cases.

But I couldn't find any kind of version information for HSSF.

Usecase: I get a lot of files from different sources and for support questions, it would be very helpful to know the Excel version a particular source uses. As you can also save a `.xlsx` as `.xls`, the BIFF version alone would not be of much help.